# Wagmi throws "Cannot Decode Zero Data" Error when using useContractRead

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, wagmi

I am using wagmi with next 13, and trying to call "view" function in my contract.
The function in my contract:

```
function getAllGrids() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return allGrids;
  }
```

But when I call:

```
const { data, error, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, internal} = useContractRead({
      address: `0x${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRID_FACTORY_ADDRESS}` ?? "",
      abi: gridAbi,
      functionName: "getAllGrids",
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
app-index.js:32 ContractFunctionExecutionError: Cannot decode zero data ("0x") with ABI parameters.

Raw Call Arguments:
  to:    0x821B8316C6da27e83eEF6782AF6Be1b79f894701
  data:  0x9e0c3ead
 
Contract Call:
  address:   0x821B8316C6da27e83eEF6782AF6Be1b79f894701
  function:  getCountry()

Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/readContract.html
Version: viem@1.0.7
    at getContractError (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/viem/dist/esm/utils/errors/getContractError.js:31:12)
    at readContract (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/viem/dist/esm/actions/public/readContract.js:64:98)
    at async Object.eval [as queryFn] (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/wagmi/dist/index.js:1312:12)
```

I am running a local ganache chain and my config is:

```
const { chains, publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
  [polygonMumbai, goerli, mainnet],
  [
    jsonRpcProvider({
      rpc: (chain) => ({
        http: `http://127.0.0.1:7545`,
      }),
    }),
    publicProvider(),
  ],
);

export const connectorMetaMask = new MetaMaskConnector({
  chains: [goerli],
});

const config = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: [new InjectedConnector({ chains }), connectorMetaMask],
  publicClient,
  webSocketPublicClient,
  // storage: createStorage({ storage: new PrismaClient() }),
});
```

**PS**: I don't know if it helps, but the useContractWrite executes properly and even when i try to call the contracts from remix they work properly. I also tried using readContract() from core wagmi but same error.